# creating a customized non_linearity like relu6

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras, relu

can someone help me to find the function which allow me to fix a threshold (maximum) not to exceed  like in relu6 .

i tried

```
 X = max(X , 6)
```

but I recived this error :

> (OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function )

. 
thank you in advance

Comment: Try using `tf.nn.relu6` : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/relu6

Comment: i m trying to experimet new things with my new architecture  but i will do it if have no choice . thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
X = tf.math.maximum(X,6)
```

Details here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/maximum

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you verry much i tried it but i recived that error :  

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'